# Acrobat 9 on Ubuntu 14

Tags: adobe-reader

I've got the newest possible version of `Acrobat` that is available for Linux.

From time to time I get `RSException` from acroread. 
Does anyone know what's the reason of this exception and how I could fix that issue?

The exact message is:

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'RSException'